# Problema com Bind em C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Tenho um WPF que está da seguinte forma:

```
 <ComboBox Name="comboBoxRemetente" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="20"
              ItemsSource ="{Binding Path=Lista, Mode = TwoWay}" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Model, Mode = TwoWay}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Remetente"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              SelectedIndex="0"
    >
    </ComboBox>
<DataGrid Name="GridLista" 
                     Grid.ColumnSpan="20" 
                     Margin="5" 
                     Grid.RowSpan="11" 
                     Grid.Row="8"
                     CanUserAddRows="False"
                     CanUserReorderColumns="True"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                     SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                     SelectionMode="Extended"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lista}"
                     SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Model, Mode = TwoWay}"
                     IsReadOnly="True"
              >
```

Entao, Quando inicio a tela eu carrego a lista PAI e ela preenche os campos quase  que tudo corretamente. Meu problema é:

Tenho esse combobox:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBoxCartao" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" Margin="5" Grid.Column="2"
              ItemsSource ="{Binding Path=CartaoBean.Lista, Mode = TwoWay}" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Model.Cartao, Mode = TwoWay}"
              DisplayMemberPath="ToComboBox"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              SelectedIndex="0"
    >
    </ComboBox>
```

Esse ultimo combobox carrega uma lista de FILHOS, na CLASSE PAI eu tenho setado esse um filho, então preciso que ao selecionar um PAI, ele também selecione o FILHO nesse combobox, poderiam me ajudar onde estou errando? rs

Metodo Hash do Cartão:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var cart = obj as CartaoPostagemModel;
        if (cart == null) return false;
        return cart.Cartao == this.Cartao;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            int hash = 17;
            // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
            hash = hash * 23 + Id.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + Cartao.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + Contrato.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você pode melhorar e/ou contextualizar sua pergunta? O que você quer é selecionar um item padrão para o combo Cartão quando o item principal (X) é alterado?

Comment: Tenho um combobox que você seleciona o PAI(remetente) dentro do PAI tem um FILHO(cartao), tenho um outro combobox que tem uma lista de FILHO(cartao) entao meu desejo é: quando eu seleciono o PAI ele ve a lista de filho, e o seleciona também, consegui explicar? rs

Comment: Então você tem um combobox com uma lista de cartões e quer que alguns sejam selecionados de acordo com o remetente escolhido certo? Por exemplo, no combobox tem 10 cartões, mas o remente possui somente 3 cadastrados. Ao selecionar o remente, você quer que apareçam os 3 selecionados?

Comment: quase isso, no caso deste exemplo, o combobox tem 10 cartoes, e preciso que dentre os 10 cartoes cadastrados, seja selecionado somente 1 cartão que é o cadastrado dentro do Remetente, agora foi? rs

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente, seu problema, é por causa do uso de binding por objeto. O C# (não é uma questão do WPF) não sabe quando dois objetos são iguais se eles não forem a mesma instância. Para resolver isso, você pode:

1 - Sobrescrever o método Equals

```
class Cartao {

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var cart = obj as Cartao;

            if (cart == null) return false;
            return cart.Numero == this.Numero;

        }
}
```

2 - Trocar o binding por um campo chave. Bom, neste caso é um pouco mais trabalhoso, porque você precisa usar o campo chave e também trocar a instância, caso utilize instância na classe Rementente, sempre que a opção for trocada:

XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBoxCartao" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" Margin="5" Grid.Column="2"
              ItemsSource ="{Binding Path=CartaoBean.Lista, Mode = TwoWay}"              
              SelectedValuePath="Cartao_Id"           
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Model.CartaoView, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Model.Cartao_Id, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              DisplayMemberPath="ToComboBox"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              SelectedIndex="0">
</ComboBox>
```

C#

```
private CartaoViewData CartaoView;

public CartaoViewData CartaoView
{
    get { return CartaoView; }
    set
    {
        CartaoView = value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CartaoView));

        if (value == null)
        {
            Cartao_Id = null;
        }
        else
        {
            Cartao_Id = value.Id;
        }

    }
}

public int? Cartao_Id
{
    get { return _CartaoId; }
    set
    {
        _CartaoId = value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Cartao_Id));
    }
}
```

Comment: se eu falar bobagem me corrija por favor, mas pelo que eu entendi Multiselect Combobox é para selecionar varios ao mesmo tempo, no meu caso eu preciso que seja selecionado somente um, não uma lista é como se fosse selecionar o primeiro item após carregar a lista, porem no meu caso eu tenho que selecionar um item que está em uma determinada posição, no meu caso está mais para um single select

Comment: Você tem razão, eu não prestei atenção ao "somente" da frase. Atualizei minha resposta

Comment: então fiz o mais pratico que você me disse, porem ele continua não selecionando, tem mais alguma coisa de errado no que fiz?

Comment: Se não estiver dando erro de binding (isso você verificar na janela Output quando mudar a seleção), pode ser que você precise implementar a interface INotifyPropertyChanged, e notificar quando a propriedade Model for alterada. Desta forma o WPF saberá que você alterou (selecinou) o remetente e disparará seu fluxo de atualização da tela (o TwoWay na sua classe se você implementar esta interface). Dê uma olhada no exemplo https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification